# DataFrame returns Value Error after adding auto index

Tags: python, pandas

This script needs to query the DC server for events. Since this is done live, each time the server is queried, it returns query results of varying lengths. The log file is long and messy, as most logs are. I need to filter only the event names and their codes and then create a DataFrame. Additionally, I need to add a third column that counts the number of times each event took place. I've done most of it but can't figure out how to fix the error I'm getting.

After doing all the filtering from Elasticsearch, I get two lists - action and code - which I have emulated here.

```
action_list = ['logged-out', 'logged-out', 'logged-out', 'Directory Service Access', 'Directory Service Access', 'Directory Service Access', 'logged-out', 'logged-out', 'Directory Service Access', 'created-process', 'created-process']

code_list = ['4634', '4634', '4634', '4662', '4662', '4662', '4634', '4634', '4662','4688']
```

I then created a list that contains only the codes that need to be filtered out.

```
event_code_list = ['4662', '4688']
```

My script is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

#Create a dict that combines action and code
lists2dict = {}
lists2dict = dict(zip(action_list,code_list))
# print(lists2dict)

#Filter only wanted eventss
filtered_events = {k: v for k, v in lists2dict.items() if v in event_code_list}
# print(filtered_events)


index = 1 * pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=2) #add automatic index to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_events,index=index)#Create DataFrame from filtered events

#Create Auto Index 
count = Counter(df)
action_count = dict(Counter(count))
action_count_values = action_count.values()
# print(action_count_values)

#Convert Columns to Rows and Add Index
new_df = df.melt(var_name="Event",value_name="Code")
new_df['Count'] = action_count_values
print(new_df)
```

Up until this point, everything works as it should. The problem is what comes next. If there are no events, the script outputs an empty DataFrame. This works fine. However, if there are events, then we should see the events, the codes, and the number of times each event occurred. The problem is that it always outputs 1. How can I fix this? I'm sure it's something ridiculous that I'm missing.

```
#If no alerts, create empty DataFrame
if new_df.empty:
    empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Event','Code','Count'])
    empty_df['Event'] = ['-']
    empty_df['Code'] = ['-']
    empty_df['Count'] = ['-']

    empty_df.to_html()
    html = empty_df.to_html()
    with open('alerts.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(html)

else: #else, output alerts + codes + count
    new_df.to_html()
    html = new_df.to_html()
    with open('alerts.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(html)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are collecting the result as dictionary - the repeated records are ignored. You lost the record count here: `lists2dict = dict(zip(action_list,code_list))`.

You can do all these operations very easily on dataframe. Just construct a pandas dataframe from given lists, then filter by code, groupby, and aggregate as count:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Event": action_list, "Code": code_list})

df = df[df.Code.isin(event_code_list)] \
       .groupby(["Event", "Code"]) \
       .agg(Count = ("Code", len)) \
       .reset_index()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      Event  Code  Count
0  Directory Service Access  4662      4
1           created-process  4688      2
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for taking the time Azhar!